# Does "I got a date with..." mean "I have a date with..."?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I've read this sentence in a text which in the tense of situation is present, so why the past tense of "get" has been used? And does that mean "I have a date with..."?

Comment: Without a full context it's impossible to say. Native speakers (esp. *Americans*) often say *"I got X"* when strictly speaking they should use *"I **have** got X"* (not to mention which Brits would more often say *"I have X"* and not use the superfluous "got" in the first place). But in other contexts, talking about having ***obtained** X* (past tense), *"I got X last night"* would be perfectly correct.

Comment: you mean in present situation "got" implies "have got" and in past "obtained"?

Comment: Yes. The verb is ***to get***, obviously, for which ***got*** can be a *Past Participle* (the *got/gotten* distinction is a separate issue) or the conjugated Simple Past. Usually, when we say *"I've got X"* the sense is more *"I'm currently in possession of X"* rather than *"I have **obtained** X"*, but it nets down to much the same thing in most contexts (if you now *have* something, most likely that's because at some point in the past you *obtained* it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more context would be nice, but generally, yes- it does mean *I have a date with [...]*

Consider this example conversation between two people:

> A- Hey, you wanna come over and study tonight?
>
> B- Sorry man, I got this party tonight.

Person B says there **is** a party tonight which he has to attend. Technically, yes the past tense of get is used. But, it's an informal way of saying there is a party tonight. You could also think of the sentence like this:

> I have got this party tonight.

OR less informally

> I have got (to attend) this party tonight.

All of them imply the same thing!

Comment: I think in OP’s case, “got” means “obtained”, referring to how the other person _gave_ the speaker their agreement to go on the date.

Answer (score 0):

*Got* also has nuanced meanings.  To use the example of the question's title: "I got a date with..."

It could mean:

**I have *succeeded in getting* that popular girl, who is much too intelligent and pretty to be dating the likes of me, to go out to dinner with me on Friday night.**

"I've got a date with ..."

would mean simply "I have a date with ...."

"I got a seat on the flight" would mean

**I *managed to get* one of the last open seats on the flight.**

Answer (score 0):

In a *literal* sense, "I got X from Y," means I *obtained* X (a date) from Y.

Sometimes, I got X is short for "I have gotten X," which better abbreviates to "I have X." In this context, "I got a date with Y can mean," "I *have* a date with Y."

Answer (score 0):

The two phrases mean different things.

> I got a date with Janet.

Let's say you have been trying to get Janet to go on a date with you. Finally she agrees. You tell your friend "I got a date with Janet". This is in the past (the agreement to the date).

> I have a date with Janet.

Now we are talking about the future. Your friend asks you to go to the movies. However you can't go because "I have a date with Janet". This (the date) is happening in the future.

The next day (after the date is over) you might tell someone:

> I had a date with Janet.

Now the date is in the past.